# The trap when using HttpWebRequest to connect to website while you are in VPN

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, vpn

I am in the Campany LAN network, in the VPN. And I am trying to use C# HttpWebRequest to visit some public website in the internet.

```
Uri URI = new Uri("http://www.baidu.com");
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URI);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

But I get the excpetion: The remote name could not be resolved

I assume maybe this is because of the VPN and it cannot get the right DNS. So I try to do it like this.

```
Uri URI = new Uri("http://202.108.22.5/");
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URI);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

But I get another exception:A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I think maybe this is a common problem in VPN, which is not to visit public website nommally using C# HttpWebRequest. Anyone have ecountered this and give a solution? thanks.

Comment: This is not a common practice. What's the use of a network without names? Does it work in your browser?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, yes, it works in my broweser. When I put http://www.baidu.com or http://202.108.22.5/ in the address line of my brower, it can get the page corrently. So this is why I am so curious about the HttpWebRequest. Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this matter, and I may be saying silliness, but probably the error comes from the fact you access those websites through another network adapter (the vpn one), and .NET is trying to go there through the default adapter?

Comment: When it works in the browser, but doesn't work with WebRequest etc., then it means the browser is set up to use a proxy server, and WebRequest is not. Look at the proxy settings of the browser.

Comment: @ConradClark yeap, I think maybe you get the point. I need to add a network adapter for the HttpWebRequest. Without the Proxy setting, the request will not reach out of the Intranet.

Comment: @ConradClark Thank you for the point. Get it.